# How to remove configure product from cart in "checkout_cart_product_add_after" observer?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, event-observer

I am facing problem when i am removing configure product from cart using `$cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();` method then its change all products price to zero. check this screen : https://prnt.sc/oagwbm

My code for removing item from cart :

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if($item->getProduct()->getId() == 208202){
        $this->_cart->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
    }
}
```

I am removing only one product from cart

Is there any other way to remove item from cart in observer ?

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: @RaviSoni Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code. It should be working fine I haven't tested it though.

```
class DeleteObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cart
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $this->cart->create()->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductType() == 'configurable') {
                $item->isDeleted(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! This $item->isDeleted(true); method solved my problem